# Why does nasdaq.com have such high Put IVs?

Tags: option-pricing, implied-volatility

For the following monthly puts, nasdaq.com has very high IVs:

```
WHR Sep 115 Put: 54.51%
WDC Sep 42.5 Put: 66.94%
```

When I run the above through http://www.option-price.com/implied-volatility.php, I get the following IVs:

```
WHR Sep 115 Put: 37.24%, days=49, interest=2.5, underlying=137.09
WDC Sep 42.5 Put: 52.52%, days=49, interest=2.5, underlying=54.03
```

Any idea why there is such a huge difference? I see this across many option IVs from nasdaq.com.

Comment: Where is your `interest=2.5` coming from?

Comment: 10-yr. Although now it is 1.88. Doesn't matter. That little bit of difference is not material.

Comment: You need to give more information on what your inputs are. Do their call and put volatilities match? Do yours? Are there dividends? How is the forward being calculated (ie what is your div yield and what is your borrow rate for the stocks)?

Comment: Do you mean such a huge difference between your IV calculations and the Nasdaq? If you send a link where I can find the IV data you have provided, I can (try) to show that the IV data provided by Nasdaq is "correct" (I think you have missed some points, regarding dividends, risk-free rate, American/European style etc.).